Docker Flask Service: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask' When Running Container, but Works Manually
I am trying to build and run a Flask-based Python service (task_manager) using Docker and Docker Compose, but I'm encountering a persistent issue. When I run the container via docker-compose up --build, the service fails to find the Flask module:
task_manager  | Traceback (most recent call last):  
task_manager  |   File "/app/task_manager.py", line 1, in <module>  
task_manager  |     from flask import Flask, jsonify  
task_manager  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'  

However, the same service works perfectly if I manually execute the following commands in PowerShell:
docker run -it --name task_manager -v D:/Projects/my_ai_assistant/task_manager:/app -w /app python:3.11-slim bash  
apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev bash && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*  
python -m venv /app/venv  
source /app/venv/bin/activate  
pip install --upgrade pip  
pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt  
/app/venv/bin/python /app/task_manager.py  

Context of the Setup:

Host OS: Windows 11
Environment:

Running Docker Desktop with Debian (via MS Store) as the WSL backend
Using PowerShell for commands


Directory Structure:

D:/Projects/my_ai_assistant/ is the root directory.
Each service (task_manager and gui_dashboard) has its own subfolder and Dockerfile.




Working Service (gui_dashboard) for Reference:
The gui_dashboard service works without issue. Its setup:
docker-compose.yml (relevant section):
gui_dashboard:  
  build:  
    context: ./gui_dashboard  
  container_name: gui_dashboard  
  working_dir: /app  
  volumes:  
    - ./gui_dashboard:/app  
  ports:  
    - "3000:3000"  
  restart: unless-stopped  
  command: ["npm", "start"]  


Problematic task_manager Service:
docker-compose.yml (relevant section):
task_manager:  
  build:  
    context: ./task_manager  
  container_name: task_manager  
  working_dir: /app  
  volumes:  
    - ./task_manager:/app  
  ports:  
    - "5000:5000"  
  environment:  
    FLASK_RUN_HOST: "0.0.0.0"  
    FLASK_RUN_PORT: "5000"  
  restart: unless-stopped  

task_manager/Dockerfile:
# Use the official Python image  
FROM python:3.11-slim  

# Set environment variables  
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1  
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1  

# Set the working directory  
WORKDIR /app  

# Install system dependencies  
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \  
    build-essential \  
    libssl-dev \  
    libffi-dev \  
    python3-dev \  
    bash && \  
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*  

# Copy application files  
COPY . /app/  

# Create a virtual environment and install dependencies  
RUN python -m venv /app/venv && \  
    source /app/venv/bin/activate && \  
    /app/venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \  
    /app/venv/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt  

# Expose Flask's default port  
EXPOSE 5000  

# Command to run the application  
CMD ["python", "/app/task_manager.py"]  


Troubleshooting Notes:

Manual Execution Works:
Manually running the steps in PowerShell, including activating the virtual environment and running the script, works flawlessly.

Mounting Filesystem:
I use -v D:/Projects/my_ai_assistant/task_manager:/app to map the local directory for visibility and avoid copying files into the container.

Experiment with CMD:
Changing the CMD to use the virtual environment explicitly:
CMD ["/app/venv/bin/python", "/app/task_manager.py"]  

Results in:
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/app/venv/bin/python": stat /app/venv/bin/python: no such file or directory: unknown  




What I Need Help With:
Why does the Flask module fail to be found (ModuleNotFoundError) during docker-compose up, even though it works manually? How can I ensure the task_manager service works as expected using Docker Compose?

Your CMD is running the system Python, not the virtual environment Python.  You'd need to explicitly run /app/venv/bin/python as the interpreter, or put the virtual environment into $PATH.  Does Activate python virtualenv in Dockerfile help you?

The other part of this is the volumes: mount that hides everything in the image's /app directory.  In general replacing the image's code with host content reintroduces the "works on my machine" problem that Docker usually tries to avoid.  More specifically here, mounting content over /app hides the /app/venv that the image installs, which leads to the "no such file or directory" error.  You should also delete the volumes: block, probably from both services.

@DavidMaze The volumes were added at some point for troubleshooting. I removed those and using the link you provided, I added ENV PATH; which required simplifying a few other paths. ITS WORKING!
